# Opening a TAB delimited CSV and Saving as TAB Delimited

Tags: excel, vba, csv

So, I have CSV file that is Tab Delimited.
I have a macro that changes the content of the file and then saves it using the code:

```
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

The problem is, it is then saved as a CSV Comma Separated.

When another routine open the file, it gets messed up.

I looked around, and I did not found a way to save the file as a TAB delimited CSV in Excel.

Can someone help me? Below is the full code:

```
    Sub routine()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Path As String 'Caminho
Dim File As String 'Arquivo da pasta
Dim Folder As FileDialog 'Pasta de origem
Dim answer As Integer

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'




answer = MsgBox("This macro will ask you to select a folder and change all the files from that folder. This action is not reversible, so make a backup before proceeding.", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Confirm Action")

If answer = vbYes Then

    Set Folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With Folder
    .Title = "Select Folder with CSV Files"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        Path = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'Caso o usuário cancele
NextCode:
    Path = Path
    If Path = "" Then GoTo Resetar
    File = Dir(Path & "*.csv*")



    Do While File <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & File)


    Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
        True


    Range("N:N, M:M, L:L, K:K, J:J, H:H, G:G, F:F, D:D, C:C ").EntireColumn.Delete
    Range("A2").EntireRow.Delete
    wb.sav
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True



    DoEvents
    File = Dir
    Loop


    MsgBox "CSV Files From Folder Updated"


Else
    GoTo Resetar


Resetar:
MsgBox "User Cancelled Action"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: A TAB delimited file is a text file, you should use a txt or tsv extension. A CSV is a Comma Separated Value file, also a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the file has a .csv instead of .txt extension. [The tab delimiter can be specified when opening](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx):

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & File, Format:=1)

Range("C:D, H:F, J:N").EntireColumn.Delete
Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Sheets(1).SaveAs Filename:=Path & File, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: @EstevaoSantiago what didn't work? I don't have Excel, so I won't be able to test it anytime soon

Comment: The saved file is outputted with commas instead of the original tabs. It seems that wb.save completely ignored the load format and "forces" the saving as a CSV with comma delimited.

Comment: @EstevaoSantiago you can try specifying the file format in SaveAs

Comment: I did as per the updated in your code. Your code does not seems to save the files. But following your logic I would need to SaveAs text tab demilimted, then create another routine to delete all the old csv and rename the existing txt to csv. I would like to avoid that...

Comment: @EstevaoSantiago There should be no need to save as different file. If the updated version doesn't work either, I give up for now

Comment: NAH! It worked! The thing is that we must inform the FileName on SaveAs, otherwise it get's saved to some temporary folder and not on the current file folder. I specified the path and file name on your SaveAs file before the FileFormat and it done the job (well... it was doing it already, just not saving on the expected place). Thanks!